# .htaccess rewrite to environment variable if folder not exists

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

What I am attempting to achieve is that if a folder does not exist on the local site a rewrite to another folder outside of the site happens.

So what we have is the actual site which document root is a web folder:

```
/mysites/site/web/
```

Then the site that holds alot of files for other sites:

```
/mysites/central/
```

The environment variable set in the vhosts file:

```
SetEnv CENTRAL_DIR "/mysites/central"
```

And the current .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^wp/(.*)$ %{ENV:CENTRAL_DIR}/wp/$1 [L]
```

So what its supposed to do, but not at the moment, is if '/mysites/sites/web/wp/...' does not exist the environment variable is used to rewrite to central '/mysites/central/wp/...'. Any help to get this working is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You cannot rewrite to an outside `DocumentRoot` handler

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was worried that would be the case. Is there no way to allow it to just on a local set up or some way to allow access, excluding the option of symlinks?